# Making DataFrame with 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

While studying, I often need to make dataframe with 2 columns like

```
index / col1 / col2
0        a      x    
1        b      y
2        c      z
```

for this, in python, my code is here:

```
Series1=pd.Series([1,2,3])
Series2=pd.Series([4,5,6])
DF=pd.DataFrame(Series1, columns=['Series1'])
DF['Series2']=Series2
```

This makes 1-col DataFrame first, and add another one in succession. I think this way is something unefficient. I want to know more efficient way to make 2=col Pandas DataFrame directly. How can I do?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'s1':Series1, 's2':Series2})`.

Comment: `pd.concat([Series1, Series2], axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first create a dict with your lists:

```
data = {'Series1':Series1, 'Series2':Series2}
```

And afterward create a panda data frame from a dict with the function: `DataFrame.from_dict()`
So in your case, it should be like this:

```
Series1= [1,2,3] 
Series2= [4,5,6]
data = {'Series1':Series1, 'Series2':Series2}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

It should be more efficient